# Traveling to Korea after having "stolen" a residence card

Tags: customs-and-immigration, south-korea

Some background on the story: In 2011, I lived in (South) Korea as an English teacher.  Due to immense bureaucratic difficulty I had trouble getting my Residence Card and only received it the Monday before the Friday that I was set to leave Korea (had unrelated issues in my workplace so I was only there for about 10 weeks).  For personal reasons, mostly to keep the residence card as a trophy because of how hard I had worked for it (see the above bureaucratic difficulty) I did not return the residence card at the airport and I lied to the official saying that I intended to return to Korea.

This was in 2011 and I have not returned to Korea since; I have not applied to renew the residence card nor to renew my visa, to the best of my knowledge I have no residence on file with any Korean agency, etc.  I'm pretty sure the passport with the original visa in it has expired and has been replaced as well; the only way the Korean government would even be able to flag me is if they put 2 and 2 together in their own system and figured it out; it's a pretty easy problem to solve but requires nonzero effort so it's entirely likely it won't matter.

I may be traveling (for tourism) to Korea soon with a friend, and I want to know what's likely to happen at immigration.  I can bring the card with me to return to them if they ask for it, but if they find the card in a search then they might think I'm planning to use it to illegally stay there (which I'm absolutely not planning on doing); conversely if I leave the card at home then I may get into trouble for not returning it (which they might forgive me if I had the card on hand to return at the time).

To be honest, I still think of that card as a trophy of my experience and I'd prefer not to return it if I don't absolutely have to, as it has sentimental value.  If I simply ignore that this situation ever happened, is it likely for the government of Korea to give me trouble if I try to enter the country?

Comment: Does it not expire after 10 years?

Comment: It probably does.  I'm just worried about being asked about it or something at the border.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't give it a second thought, just leave it home and forget about it, but that's my risk tolerance level. In the extremely unlikely situation it comes up you can say you thought you might return but things changed. Were you really 100.0000% sure  you would not return at the time? The slightest doubt makes that not a lie.

Comment: I attended a tax planning seminar for British ex-pats run by a HK legal firm (didn't apply to me, I was just bored one evening in Kowloon) and they explained that having some general intention to return to old Blighty some day was sufficient to save many hundreds of thousands of pounds in taxes when properly expressed. No plan required, just a general intention.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I was 100% sure at the time to never return for the purpose of living there; I'd quit my job, packed my stuff, etc.  Not that I can't lie to the border official a second time and tell them I thought I might return.  I have done so in the past where I thought I might return to a country I was living in and then didn't.

Comment: Was your old passport biometric?  Has your name changed since all these shenanigans? Pretty easy for S Korean authorities to flag you from eg name and date of birth, if they wanted to

Comment: @Traveller I don't remember.  It's nontrivial for them to flag me (it's very easy, but not automatic; Western governments have certainly fucked up in much easier cases than this one), my question is to what degree should I expect to be asked about this and what should I do about it?  I'm sure they're not going to ban me from the country over this, but what should I do to make this go as smoothly as possible?

Comment: Intending to return (assuming that's what you said at the time) is very different from committing, for which they'd probably want to see some sort of proof

Comment: OP if you do end up going back, let us know in an updated comment on this post

Answer (score 5):

> the only way the Korean government would even be able to flag me is if they put 2 and 2 together in their own system and figured it out;

I've lived in South Korea 15 years, and visited 200+ times since. The government has the entire record of my stays, visits, visas, etc. I was fully fingerprinted 3 times at Mokdong, and a few years ago when entering at Incheon there was a problem with my fingerprints. I was sent to secondary – although they refused to speak to me, and never told me what the problem was – but I am bilingual in Korean so I shut up and listened... :-)

They finally reconciled my file and sent me on my way: apparently my actual fingerprints were slightly different from their file...

So yes the government can track you and knows who you are. Like you, I once kept my ARC, not because I wanted a trophy, but because I was switching jobs, and had to go on a biz trip before my new visa was approved. I left, and came back, on my old ARC and visa.

Wrong move. Immigration got pissed at me and almost denied me my new visa – fortunately my employer was using the services of a very powerful law firm, and I escaped legal issues through... hmmm... persuasion by my lawyer. He wasn't very happy with me either.

Thereafter, KIS tried every year to prevent me from renewing my visa, forcing us to use the same law firm ($$$$$). They have a long memory and never forgive.

So when you show up at Incheon (or Busan or elsewhere) and they scan your passport, the system will match your data against their Big Database™ and find you. Since it's illegal to keep the ARC, but not a crime (I'd have to look up exactly what kind of offense it is), you may or may not run into trouble. The officer will have YOUR FULL RECORDS right there on their computer. Once while entering at Incheon, the officer kept scrolling, and it was taking a while. Then asked me whether I spoke Korean. "Yeah, why?" *Because your record of entries and exits is extremely long. So I suppose you learned Korean.* The officer might decide to skip the issue, or not... Women are usually stricter than men, so pick your line accordingly.

However, if you try to apply for a resident visa, you will run into issues. That missing ARC is in your file, and they will take issue. And it's not like you can pretend it's a case of mistaken identity – they have your fingerprints on file.